# Delphi XE6 App Crash when installed from Google Play Store

Tags: android, delphi, google-play, delphi-xe6

Yesterday I created an Android app using Delphi XE6, built it with Release configuration and targeted App Store, and ran deployment without installing to any device.
I then uploaded the resulted APK to Google Play Store with success, but when the app downloaded and installed on my device (ZTE N986D), it crashed.
THE SAME APK downloaded to the device via http server running on my laptop was fine and working without any error/crash.

I did triple checks everything (debug/release mode, provisioning, deployment files, etc.) with no luck. I also did try on 3 differend Android devices with exactly same result.

For now I believe that this is not a bug on Delphi XE6.

Is an APK getting changed when uploaded to Google Play Store?

Here is link to the app:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.cenadep.pnup.qrkasir

Any help and thought would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

1) You need to generate a keystore for sign your APK.
   Please follow this link to create a keystore: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE6/en/Creating_a_Keystore_File

2) After, follow this: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE6/en/Deploying_Your_Signed_Android_Application

Comment: You might want to add the necessary steps from the links into your answer because if the link should change/move your answer will no longer be valid

Comment: I did create the keystore for signing. In fact,  the APK was uploaded successfully to Google Play Store. The problem occured when app had been installed.

Comment: Figure out what the issue was?